# How to map single value for multiple ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have two dropdowns. If we select 2nd dropdown value then first dropdown value related to it will be selected.Here the issue is there are duplicate values in 2nd dropdown mapped with different values in 1st dropdown. So how to select all the values in the 1st dropdown for that single value in 2nd dropdown.

```
var firstVal =[
{ id: 1, value: 'Foo1' },
{ id: 2, value: 'Foo2' },
{ id: 3, value: 'Foo3' },]

var secondVal =[
{ id: 1, value: 'Foo1' },
{ id: [1,2] value: 'Foo11 ' },
{ id: 2, value: 'Foo2' },
{ id: 3, value: 'Foo3 ' },
{ id: 3, value: 'Foo13' },
{ id: 3, value: 'Foo112' },]

Here If I select Foo11 then in first dropdown both 1,2,3 should be selected.
```

Here in my piece of code I am getting an array where only one index i.e [0] is storing ["1,2"] so when I select foo11 in 2nd dropdown then in 1st dropdown 1,2 is not getting selected.
Here how should I break this into different index of the array.

```
$.each(secondVal, function(key,val){
$secondList.append('<option  value="' + val.id + '">' + val.value + 
'</option>');
 });

$secondList.change(function(){
   var value=[];
   value=$(this).val();
$.each(value, function(index,value){
$firstList.find('option').each(function(){
    var optVal = $(this).attr('value');if(value.indexOf(optVal) >= 0)

     $(this).addClass('reward-select');
  }else{

    $(this).removeClass('reward-select');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the **firstVal** and update the relative object to keep track of the checked fields.

Below function will take the array and selected value from **secondVal** and return a new array where the corresponding element are flagged

```
function slectFirstOption(firstVal, value) {
    return firstVal.map(row => {
          return {
             ...row,
             check: row.value === value
           }
     })
}
```